# Magento 2 - Magic getter and setters not available

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm trying to write to the database like -

```
$album = $this->_pageFactory->create('Company\Project\Model\Album');
$album->setProductId($product->getId());
$album->setProductAlbumId($albumId);
$album->save();
```

however, on the third and fourth line, I get the following error. I'm sure that albumID and product->getId() work as expected.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor::setProductId() in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/magento2/app/code/Company/Project/Helper/Data.php

My model file looks like this. You see I have tried declaring the setter methods by hand and they still don't get picked up.

```
<?php

namespace Company\Project\Model;

class Album extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel {

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\Model\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
    \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
    \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\AbstractResource $resource = null,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb $resourceCollection = null,
    array $data = []
    ) {
       $this->_logger = $logger;
       parent::__construct($context, $registry, $resource, $resourceCollection, $data);
    }

  public function _construct() {
    $this->_init('Company\Project\Model\Resource\Album');
  }

  public function setProductId($productId) {
    return $this->setData(self::PRODUCT_ID, $productId);
  }

  public function setProjectAlbumId($albumId) {
    return $this->setData(self::PROJECT_ALBUM_ID, $albumId);
  }
}
```

I'm following the pageFactory pattern from [this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/32952/how-to-instantiate-a-model-in-magento2)

Also, if there is another way in Magento 2 to achieve the same result, please do suggest. Something like making direct SQL INSERT statements would work for me.

Comment: Hi again - this again points to a problem with the fact that you're instantiating your model from a CMS page factory rather than the object manager. The magic methods work the same was as Magento 1.x for my own M2 modules.

Comment: actually, I changed that. Now I'm instantiating the model using \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory. This also got rid of the previous problem btw

Comment: That's good, but it's still a **page**. What you want is a model, and that model has nothing to do with views, pages or CMSs

Comment: Okay so what is a good file to instantiate a model then? Because using objectManager doesn't seem to work for me as I mentioned in my previous question. Even if I directly get it from \Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager

Answer (score 0):

The magic setters and getters provided by the method `\Magento\Framework\DataObject::__call` are available only on objects that inherit from class `\Magento\Framework\DataObject`. That's just how object-oriented programming works.

Looking at your model, `Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page`, it does not inherit from the aforementioned class. It's not really a questions of "which model should I use to the getters and setters". I think you should ask why you're needing magic setters on this object in the first place and save it. I didn't look too much into this `Page` object you're using, but it does not look like an object you save via `save()`.

Answer (score 0):

@musicliftsme answer is right, can't use getter and setter without extending `\Magento\Framework\DataObject.`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).